# How to get 2nd Last Record using Jpa query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

This is my oracle query which is giving right result.
SELECT * FROM(SELECT a.*, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ELB_ID DESC) rn FROM BILL a) where rn=2 AND ACCOUNT_ID=486;

Comment: and what have you tried? and have you used setMaxResults, setFirstResult ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to revert your query by changing order by ELB_ID into ASC and by using setFirstResult and setMaxResults:

```
TypedQuery<Bill> q = entityManager.createQuery("select a from Bill a where a.accountId=:accountId order by a.elbId");
q.setParameter("accountId", 486);
q.setFirstResult(2);
q.setMaxResults(1);
```